# USB Microphone (webcam) and JACK, Ubuntu Studio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, ubuntu-studio, jack

I have a slightly old webcam I'm using with my desktop. The camera seems to work fine, but I'm having issues with the mic. If I stop JACK and only use PulseAudio, it works fine, but as soon as I start JACK, I get nothing.

Looking at QASMixer and Pulse Control, when JACK is stopped, hw: Card, USB Device (...) is connected

[QASMixer, JACK Stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNuz1.png)

[Pulse, JACK stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQWxV.png)

When JACK is started, pulse: Device (Capture) is connected

[QASMixer, JACK started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwaUj.png)

[Pulse, JACK started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG3mN.png)

Here is what Ubuntu Studio Controls looks like. There is no option to select for system:capture_

[Ubuntu Studio Controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEEZ9.png)

Is there a way to make the mic work with JACK, or do I have to switch it off anytime I use that mic. I can make it work when I connect a different mic through an audio interface.

Answer (score 1):

The webcam should show up in Carla, not in Pulseaudio. When Jack is started by Ubuntu Studio Controls, Pulseaudio becomes a "device" as recognized by Jack. Therefore, your USB webcam mic would show up in the Carla patchbay as a device. Pulseaudio should only recognize "Jack Sink" or "Jack Source".

Comment: Thank you. Hadn't looked at Carla before, but I had looked at QjackCtl. Device didn't show up until I switched to 48k. All good now.